# Swaps: Why is this approximation of carry valid?

Tags: interest-rate-swap

I decided to split the first part of my original [question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/72099/carry-and-roll-of-an-asset-swap) into this separate one as they are somewhat unrelated.
The definition of carry of a (spot) starting swap I know is $$\frac{S(0, T) - F(0,\tau)}{DV01(Swap(\tau, T-\tau))}\tag{1}$$
where $S(0,T)$ is the swap rate for maturity $T$, $F(0,\tau)$ is the fixing with period $\tau$ and $DV01(Swap(\tau, T-\tau))$ is the dollar value of basis point of a swap starting in $\tau$ with time to maturity $T-\tau$, e.g. see this short [research paper](https://corporate.nordea.com/api/research/attachment/2796) from Nordea. Why can $(1)$ be approximated by $S(\tau, T-\tau)-S(0,T)$ as it is done in the Nordea paper?